# Adding supplier name to product listing

Tags: odoo, product

Using OpenERP 7

I have a client that needs to see the supplier name (Just one if there are multiple suppliers) in the product listing. I've tried using related fields but can't seem to get the syntax right. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Please specify the system you're using!

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible to define related field to one2many, in the product object have one2many product.supplierinfo object, so if you want to get only one supplier name then define a function field to get supplier name